# how to pass php array value to javascript without using JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple calculation from php database, which needs to be used in javascript, how to do it?

```
    <script>
    function check(){
    var ramt=document.getElementByName('refundedamount[]');
    var bal1=[];
    <?php for each($balance1 as $val){
    echo 'bal1.push('.$val.');';
    } ?>
    . . .  
    } </script>

    <form onsubmit="return check()";
    <?php
    $balance1=array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $income=$row['totalincome'];
    $exp=$row['totalexp'];
    $balance=$income-$exp;
    $balance1[]=$balance;
    ...... ?>
   <input type="text" name="refundedamount[]"/>
   </form>
```

How to use and read values of `$balance1[]` array into `JAVASCRIPT`. without using JSON. basically I want to cross check the value of php $balance1 array and input text array " refundedamount[]".

Comment: You may consider to convert the php array into JSON format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: I didnt know that you dont want to use JSON. I updated my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without JSON, you can loop each value.

```
<?php 
    $balance1 = array( 1,2,3,4,5 );
?>

<script>
    var balance1 = [];
    <?php
    foreach( $balance1 as $val ) {
        echo 'balance1.push( ' . $val .  ' );';
    }
   ?>
   console.log( balance1 );
</script>
```

Will result to

```
Array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: Working on my end. Can you update your post so that I can check?

Comment: @haju You are putting the values on javascript before you assign the value on php. You should assign the value on php first before you can assign on js

Comment: its an onsubmit function, and i couldnt get u. do you mean i dont have to put js code in <head> section.

Comment: But `$balance1` should have a value before you loop on js.

Comment: it working, thanks... just a sily positioning of js codes

Answer (score 0):

**PHP side:**

`$arrayJSON = json_encode($balance1)` to convert to `JSON` format.

**JS side:**

```
var array = JSON.parse("<?php echo $arrayJSON;?>");
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the php array into a javascript object then convert that object into an array, eg if it has numeric indices:

```
<script>

var obj = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray) ?>;
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k] });

// Or if you're using ES6
var arr = Object.values(obj);

</script>
```